How to get agents in main to interact with a node inside another agent
I'm working on implementing a line of sight/vision cone in Anylogic and I've hit a couple roadblocks. My primary question is how to get agents to provide contacts with a node inside another agent, but I'll also show the other attempts I tried and gave up on in case those have more merit.
My "Teacher" agent has a 'los' cone to represent it's field of view. I have restrictions on and applied to "Student". On enter, students should be added to 'losTargets'. On exit, they should be removed from 'losTargets'. However, they don't seem to ever enter or exit because they aren't interacting with the node at all. My hypothesis is that because los is within Teacher, the students in Main cant interact with it. Is there a way to make them interact?
Pallet view of Teacher
Properties of los
Another implementation I tried was finding all students in a range, then detecting if the position of those students was inside the vision cone using los.contains(student.getX(), student.getY()). This also could not detect the students, and after consulting the Anylogic Help page I believe it's because the node is in local space (relative to teacher) whereas the students are in global space (relative to main). If this is the issue, I'm not sure how to fix that. If this implementation has more merit and is worth pursuing I can break it off into a new question, but in this case it's mostly provided for context.
Properties of losGetTarget - manually checking for students in range
I looked into these two stackoverflow questions prior to posting but they didn't prove very helpful.
How can I communicate with another agent (anylogic) within certain vision angle?
How can I get node restrictions applied in an agent type's interface to take effect in the main agent when I run the model?


This also could not detect the students, and after consulting the Anylogic Help page I believe it's because the node is in local space (relative to teacher) whereas the students are in global space (relative to main). If this is the issue, I'm not sure how to fix that.

This is the issue. You need to manually compute if another agent would be inside that node that really only exists in the teacher agent. You need manual Java code for that:

Compute the relative position of a student agent to your teacher agent (say x=4 and y=5 from "me")
Now you can check within the teacher agent if the relative point x=4,y=5 is inside the node or not (node.contains(...))

Re step 1: say your student is at the global position x=40,y=45 (on Main!) and your teacher is at x=22,y=20 -> then the relative position would be x=18,y=25 (the student relative to the teacher).
Do that for each student and each teacher agent regularly and you have your functionality

Thank you, this response was very helpful! To anyone else with this problem in the future, remember to also factor in the rotation of the reference object if that's relevant to your situation.

Pls upvote if it was helpful, helps future users with similar issues
